# Json generator with list of records from Salesforce

Tags: apex, rest-api, http, jsongenerator

I'm new in Apex and we have requirement, I need to send a record from salesforce to external system using Rest API whenever a record is created in Salesforce, I need to send couple of SF fields to external system along with External system required fields. I created a class which has both Json generaotor and Http post method however this code is working with only one record, I'm not sure how to create a list of records to so that when user creates a record in Salesforce, only that record should go to external system.

Apex class

```
public class RadarUpdate {
@future (callout=true)
public static void postcallout(string id) {   
Patient_Satisfaction__c c = [select id, Name, Reporter_First_Name__c, Reporter_Last_Name__c, 
Reporter_Phone__c, Description_of_Feedback__c from Patient_Satisfaction__c] ;
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
gen.writeStartObject();
gen.writeObjectField('First name ', c.Reporter_First_Name__c);
gen.writeObjectField('Last name',c.Reporter_Last_Name__c);
gen.writeObjectField('Phone',c.Reporter_Phone__c);
gen.writeObjectField('description',c.Description_of_Feedback__c);
gen.writeObjectField('Name',c.Name);
gen.writeObjectField('incident_group_id',7387);
gen.writeEndObject();
String jsonS = gen.getAsString(); 
System.debug('jsonMaterials'+jsonS);
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://api.radarfirst.com/incidents');
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json;charset=UTF-8');
request.setHeader('User-agent', 'Salesforce-integration-client');
request.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer abc');
request.setBody(jsonS);
// Set the body as a JSON object
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
    response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
} else {
System.debug(response.getBody());
}
}
```

}

Comment: In almost all cases it is a better idea to define an Apex class containing the properties you want and serialize that, or a list of that class, rather than writing explicit JSONGenerator code. Here that's rather hard because one of your keys contains not just spaces but _trailing_ spaces. Are you able to change (fix?) that JSON structure?

Comment: Please do not overwrite your questions once they have been answered by the community. You should use _one_ question for _one_ problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gen.writeStartArray()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_JsonGenerator.htm#apex_System_JsonGenerator_writeStartArray) and [gen.writeEndArray()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_JsonGenerator.htm#apex_System_JsonGenerator_writeEndArray) to create an array and then write list of objects.

**Sample Code**

```
    JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
    gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeFieldName('Patient Satisfactions');
        gen.writeStartArray();
            for (Patient_Satisfaction__c  patientSatisfaction : patientSatisfactions) {
                gen.writeStartObject();
                gen.writeStringField('First name', patientSatisfaction.Reporter_First_Name__c);
                gen.writeStringField('Last name', patientSatisfaction.Reporter_Last_Name__c);
                gen.writeStringField('Phone', patientSatisfaction.Reporter_Phone__c);
                gen.writeStringField('description', patientSatisfaction.Description_of_Feedback__c);
                gen.writeStringField('Name', patientSatisfaction.Name);
                gen.writeNumberField('incident_group_id', 7387);
                gen.writeEndObject();
            }
        gen.writeEndArray();
    gen.writeEndObject();
    String jsonS = gen.getAsString();
```

> As mentioned by @David it's better to use an Apex class with properties in it. As some of the property names have spaces in between, you can create variable names with '__' instead of space and do a final replaceAll from '_' to ' ' on the serialized version.

Comment: Not working? Are you getting any error or you are expecting something else.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  i guess the problem is declaring a list variable. The original code was working only when I enter clause limit 1 in SOQL query and system was pulling   values from one random record in salesforce Patient satisfaction object and creating a record in external system. The only problem is how do i make it pull the values of the record which is being inserted from trigger. Any idea?